# my news div scrolling ...i want to make it fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is my news div with scrolling from bottom to up. but it takes time to start scrolling ...i want to make it fast ..
here this div appears from my system y axix ...but actually i just want div start from exact where i define.My scrolling div is actually inside another div ,but the animation start from bottom of the system screen.Actually this should start from inside of the specific div

```css
.example1 {
  -moz-transform: translateY(10%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10%);
  transform: translateY(10%);
  /* Apply animation to this element */
  -moz-animation: example1 2s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: example1 2s linear infinite;
  /*animation: example1 22s linear infinite;*/
  animation: example1 70s linear infinite;
}


/* Move it (define the animation) */

@-moz-keyframes example1 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(10%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-10%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes example1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10%);
  }
}

@keyframes example1 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(10%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    transform: translateY(50%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-10%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    transform: translateY(-10%);
  }
}
```

```html
<?php
                  $upcoming_news = $this->mastermodel->get_upcoimg_news();
              ?>

  <div class="example1" id="example1">
    <ul <?php if($this->lang->lang()=='ar') { ?> dir="RTL"
      <?php } ?>>
      <?php
                         foreach ($upcoming_news as $row) {
                              if ($this->lang->lang() == 'ar')
                                $news = $row['news_description_ar'];
                              else
                                 $news = $row['news_description_en'];
                                                    ?>
        <li <?php if($this->lang->lang()=='ar') { ?> dir="RTL" style="text-align:right"
          <?php } ?>>
          <?= $news; ?> <br />
        </li>
        <?php
                                                }
                                                ?>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle. Very difficult to see what you exactly want

Comment: I think ,here they wants animation starts from div instead bottom of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Your time in `animation: example1 70s linear infinite;` is really long. Try changing that to 2s.

Look at this : https://jsfiddle.net/3ce7309o/

Comment: thank u..but  this is not my problem ... my scrolling div is actually inside another div and when its run it start from bottom of the system screen...and when it reaches in example1 named div it takes time..

Answer (score 0):

Try and change your value as `animation: example1 2s linear infinite;` like that for speeding up the animation. Your code was right but the time for the animation is very long.

Also please make sure you have same values for these two as well. `-moz-animation:`, `-webkit-animation:`

```css
.example1 {
  -moz-transform: translateY(10%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10%);
  transform: translateY(10%);
  /* Apply animation to this element */
  -moz-animation: example1 2s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: example1 2s linear infinite;
  animation: example1 2s linear infinite;
}


/* Move it (define the animation) */

@-moz-keyframes example1 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(10%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-10%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes example1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10%);
  }
}

@keyframes example1 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(10%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    transform: translateY(50%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-10%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    transform: translateY(-10%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="example1" id="example1">
  <ul>
    <li>Quisque a ipsum vulputate, aliquam nibh et, euismod purus.</li>
    <li>Nulla et metus laoreet, commodo turpis eget, venenatis nibh.</li>
    <li>Praesent varius nunc et accumsan fermentum.</li>
    <li>Duis vitae nisi posuere, efficitur turpis in, sollicitudin ipsum.</li>
    <li>Sed vel lorem vehicula, molestie enim vel, scelerisque nisl.</li>
    <li>Maecenas feugiat nibh non tincidunt blandit.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank u..but  this is not my problem ... my scrolling div is actually inside another div and when its run it start from bottom of the system screen...and when it reaches in example1 named div it takes time..